# Android SearchView AutocompleteTextView showdropdown BadTokenException

Tags: android

In my android application, there is a SearchView. When I add text to SearchView, it shows the search result as dropdown. But for some devices I got BadTokenException. How can I solve this? Please help.

Here is my code:

```
searchView = (SearchView) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.searchViewCustomer);
    searchView.setIconified(false);
    searchView.clearFocus();


    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(this);
    mSearchViewAdapter = new SearchFeedResultsAdaptorCustomer(this.getActivity(), R.layout.searchview_customer, null,
            columns, null, -1000);
    searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(mSearchViewAdapter);
    int autoCompleteTextViewID = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
    AutoCompleteTextView searchAutoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(autoCompleteTextViewID);
    searchAutoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);
    ((searchAutoCompleteTextView)).setDropDownWidth(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    ((searchAutoCompleteTextView)).showDropDown();
```

Here is my log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nybsys.tillbox/com.nybsys.tillbox.sales.MainActivity}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3779)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:150)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1286)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:788)
 at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:265)
 at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
 at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:1044)
 at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown(PopupWindow.java:950)
 at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:646)
 at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1108)
 at com.nybsys.tillbox.sales.FragmentOne.onCreateView(FragmentOne.java:124)
 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1230)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2042)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:165)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:543)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1181)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5277)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3779) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:150) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1286) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things you can try:

1.

```
    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            searchAutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown();
        }
    });
```

2. Set a flag to expand the dropdown that you can check in `onResume()` and call `showDropDown()` there.